# Android Background Polling and User Interface

Tags: android, polling

I am building an application that currently runs as a standalone application that polls a service using an AsyncTask.  I would like to move the polling to an Android Service that runs upon start and potentially notifies the user about changes.  The curve ball is I need to share this data across activities (and soon-to-be Service) so I don't consume the battery with all of the back and forth between persisted and in-memory storage.

Is there a way to create a service that runs in the background, polls every half minute using AlarmManager, that shares (via constants) data with a User Interface that can be launched via clicking on a notification the service creates or via the launcher itself?

Right now this is how far I have gotten:

Here is the service:

```
public class PollService extends Service {
    private final IBinder binder = new PollBinder();

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        SharedData.update();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    public class PollBinder extends Binder {
        PollService getService() {
            return PollService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

This will trigger the service...

```
public class PollScheduleReceiver extends RoboBroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int POLL_FREQ_SEC = 30;
    @Override
    protected void handleReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent schedulerIntent = new Intent(context, PollStartReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingSchedulerIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, schedulerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, POLL_FREQ_SEC);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), POLL_FREQ_SEC * 1000, pendingSchedulerIntent);
    }
}
```

This will trigger the trigger upon boot:

```
public class PollStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent pollService = new Intent(context, PollService.class);
        context.startService(pollService);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I got your question, but as far as I got it can be done in few steps..

1) Start a service so it will run in background

2) Polling could be done in that service with the help of AsyncTask or Handler every 30 Sec as u wish

3) And when the condition satisfies, start desired Activity from that service.